# Problem in setting route in app using google API

Tags: android, kotlin, directions

I am trying to add direction route from my current location to destination. I have done my code and following a tutorial for that but the app is crashing again and again. I do not understand what is wrong. I am sharing my code here. The issue is not resolving and there is no capacity for lagcat to share here body limit is full.

```
class ViewDirections : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {
    private lateinit var mService : GoogleService
    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
     var polyline: Polyline? = null


    lateinit var mCurrentMarker : Marker
    private lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private lateinit var locationRequest: LocationRequest
    private lateinit var locationCallback: LocationCallback
    lateinit var mLastLocation : Location



    //private var permissions : Array<String> = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)

    companion object {
        private const val PERMISSION_REQUEST: Int = 10
    }

    private fun buildLocationRequest() {
        locationRequest = LocationRequest()
        locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        locationRequest.interval = 5000
        locationRequest.fastestInterval = 3000
        locationRequest.smallestDisplacement = 10f

    }
    private fun buildLocationCallback() {
        locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(p0: LocationResult?) {
                //Get Last location
                mLastLocation = p0!!.lastLocation

                val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
                    .position(LatLng(mLastLocation.latitude,mLastLocation.longitude))
                    .title("My Position")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))


                mCurrentMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions)

                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(LatLng(mLastLocation.latitude,mLastLocation.longitude)))
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11f))


                val destinationLatLng = LatLng(Common.currentResults!!.geometry!!.location!!.lat,
                    Common.currentResults!!.geometry!!.location!!.lng)

                mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(destinationLatLng)
                    .title(Common.currentResults!!.name))
                    .setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW))

                //Get Direction
                drawPath(mLastLocation,Common.currentResults!!.geometry!!.location!!)



            }
        }
    }
    private fun drawPath(mLastLocation: Location?, location : com.malik.testapplication.Model.Location)     {
        if (polyline!= null)
            polyline!!.remove()

        val origin = StringBuilder(mLastLocation!!.latitude.toString())
            .append(",")
            .append(mLastLocation.longitude.toString())
            .toString()

        val destination = StringBuilder(location.lat.toString())
            .append(",")
            .append(location.lng.toString())
            .toString()

        mService.getDirections(origin,destination)
            .enqueue(object : Callback<String>{
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<String>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.d("Kotlin",t.message)
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call<String>, response: Response<String>) {
                    ParserTask().execute(response.body()!!.toString())
                } })

    }
    override fun onStop() {
        fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)
        super.onStop() }
    private fun checkLocationPermission(): Boolean {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                    ViewDirections.PERMISSION_REQUEST
                )
            else
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                    ViewDirections.PERMISSION_REQUEST
                )
            return false
        } else
            return true
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_directions)
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
        mService = Common.googleApiScalarService

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkLocationPermission()) {
                buildLocationRequest()
                buildLocationCallback()

                fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
                fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(
                    locationRequest,
                    locationCallback,
                    Looper.myLooper()

                )
            } else {
                buildLocationRequest()
                buildLocationCallback()

                fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
                fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(
                    locationRequest,
                    locationCallback,
                    Looper.myLooper()
                )
            }
        }

    }
    //@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        when (requestCode) {
            ViewDirections.PERMISSION_REQUEST -> {
                if ((grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                    // Toast.makeText(this, "Location is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                            this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    )
                        if (checkLocationPermission()) {
                            buildLocationRequest()
                            buildLocationCallback()

                            fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
                            fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(
                                locationRequest,
                                locationCallback,
                                Looper.myLooper()
                            )
                            mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true
                        }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission is denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }


    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap
        mMap.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = true

        fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener { location ->

            mLastLocation = location
            val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
                .position(LatLng(mLastLocation.latitude,mLastLocation.longitude))
                .title("My Position")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))
            mCurrentMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions)
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(LatLng(mLastLocation.latitude,mLastLocation.longitude)))
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11f))


            val destinationLatLng = LatLng(Common.currentResults!!.geometry!!.location!!.lat,
                Common.currentResults!!.geometry!!.location!!.lng)

            mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(destinationLatLng)
                .title(Common.currentResults!!.name))
                .setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW))

            //Get Direction
            drawPath(mLastLocation,Common.currentResults!!.geometry!!.location!!)


        }
    }
    inner class ParserTask : AsyncTask<String,Int,List<List<HashMap<String,String>>>>() {
        internal val waitingDialog : AlertDialog = SpotsDialog(this@ViewDirections)

        override fun onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute()
            waitingDialog.show()
            waitingDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...")
        }
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String?): List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>? {
            val jsonObject : JSONObject
            var routes : List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>? =null
            try {
                jsonObject = JSONObject(params[0])
                val parser = DirectionJSONParser()
                routes = parser.parse(jsonObject)
            }catch (e : JSONException){
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            return routes
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>?) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)

            var points : ArrayList<LatLng>
            var polylineOptions : PolylineOptions? = null

            for(i in result!!.indices){
                points = ArrayList()
                polylineOptions = PolylineOptions()

                val path  =result[i]

                for (j in path.indices){
                    val point = path[j]
                    val lat = point["lat"]!!.toDouble()
                    val lng = point["lng"]!!.toDouble()
                    val position = LatLng(lat,lng)

                    points.add(position)
                }
                polylineOptions.addAll(points)
                polylineOptions.width(12f)
                polylineOptions.color(Color.RED)
                polylineOptions.geodesic(true)

            }
            polyline = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions)
            waitingDialog.dismiss()

        }

    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
2018-11-16 15:04:40.817 4720-16409/? E/ActivityManager: getPackageFromAppProcesses, return null :22519
2018-11-16 15:04:40.861 22522-22522/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2018-11-16 15:04:40.873 2602-3503/? E/audio_hw_primary: adev_close_input_stream, set jack_in to null
2018-11-16 15:04:40.902 22506-22506/? E/appproc: Enhanced Zygote ASLR: ro.knox.enhance.zygote.aslr != 1. Enhanced Zygote ASLR is DISABLED!
2018-11-16 15:04:40.923 18326-18326/? E/adbd: recv: OPEN 0000001e 00000000 000b:6A 64 77 70 3A 32 32 35 32 32 00 
2018-11-16 15:04:41.153 22506-22506/? E/SemAffinityControl: SemAffinityControl: registerfunction enter
2018-11-16 15:04:41.430 4720-4804/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{856ed4e u0 com.sec.android.app.launcher/com.sec.android.app.launcher.activities.LauncherActivity EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false win.mViewVisibility=8, caller=com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:748 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:732 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5523 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowAnimator.stepAnimationLocked:517 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.stepAppWindowsAnimation:1745 
2018-11-16 15:04:42.026 5354-5397/? E/RequestManager_FLP: [LocationManagerService] Location request bdc04d3 gps interval=5000 from com.google.android.gms.persistent
2018-11-16 15:04:42.027 4720-5491/? E/PermissionMonitor: (NameNotFoundException) ApplicationInfo for (com.google.uid.shared) is null! UserId: 0
2018-11-16 15:04:42.066 5354-5397/? E/RequestManager_FLP: [LocationManagerService] Location request bdc04d3 gps interval=5000 from com.google.android.gms.persistent
2018-11-16 15:04:42.394 4720-4804/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{40cef14 u0 Splash Screen com.malik.testapplication EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true win.mViewVisibility=0, caller=com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:748 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:732 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5523 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.stepAnimationLocked:553 com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.lambda$-com_android_server_wm_DisplayContent_21292:465 
2018-11-16 15:04:52.130 4720-4804/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{23c455b u0 com.malik.testapplication/com.malik.testapplication.MapsActivity EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false win.mViewVisibility=8, caller=com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:748 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:732 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5523 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.stepAnimationLocked:553 com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.lambda$-com_android_server_wm_DisplayContent_21292:465 
2018-11-16 15:04:52.176 5354-5397/? E/RequestManager_FLP: [LocationManagerService] Location remove bdc04d3 from com.google.android.gms.persistent
2018-11-16 15:04:53.157 5354-5397/? E/RequestManager_FLP: [LocationManagerService] Location request d21d6b8 gps interval=5000 from com.google.android.gms.persistent
2018-11-16 15:04:53.160 4720-5801/? E/PermissionMonitor: (NameNotFoundException) ApplicationInfo for (com.google.uid.shared) is null! UserId: 0
2018-11-16 15:04:53.708 4720-4804/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{72d604 u0 com.malik.testapplication/com.malik.testapplication.ViewPlaces EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false win.mViewVisibility=8, caller=com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:748 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:732 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5523 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowAnimator.stepAnimationLocked:517 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.stepAppWindowsAnimation:1745 
2018-11-16 15:04:54.033 22522-22522/com.malik.testapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.malik.testapplication, PID: 22522
    kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at com.malik.testapplication.ViewDirections$drawPath$1.onResponse(ViewDirections.kt:117)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
2018-11-16 15:04:54.823 4720-5167/? E/LightsService: Light requested not available on this device. 2
2018-11-16 15:04:55.320 4720-4730/? E/KioskModeService: There's no matched data
2018-11-16 15:04:55.341 4720-4730/? E/KioskModeService: There's no matched data
2018-11-16 15:04:55.363 4720-4730/? E/KioskModeService: There's no matched data
2018-11-16 15:04:55.384 4720-4730/? E/ActivityManager: Found activity ActivityRecord{465da4e u0 com.malik.testapplication/.MapsActivity t-1 f} in proc activity list using null instead of expected ProcessRecord{414662d 22522:com.malik.testapplication/u0a246}
2018-11-16 15:04:55.417 4720-4736/? E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() returned.
2018-11-16 15:04:55.439 12234-12234/? E/PBSessionCacheImpl: sessionId[53807243290634637] not persisted.
2018-11-16 15:04:55.478 5354-5397/? E/RequestManager_FLP: [LocationManagerService] Location remove d21d6b8 from com.google.android.gms.persistent
2018-11-16 15:04:55.676 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.lockbox, , 1]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.679 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.lockbox, tayb125.ta@gmail.com, 1]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.680 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.easysignin, , 1]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.681 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.easysignin, tayb125.ta@gmail.com, 1]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.682 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.netrec, , 216]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.685 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.netrec, tayb125.ta@gmail.com, 216]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.687 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.subscriptions, , 205]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.688 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.subscriptions, tayb125.ta@gmail.com, 205]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.689 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.auth_api_phone, , 208]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.690 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.auth_api_phone, tayb125.ta@gmail.com, 208]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.691 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.beacon, , 232]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.692 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.beacon, tayb125.ta@gmail.com, 232]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.693 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.trustlet_place, , 205]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.694 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.trustlet_place, tayb125.ta@gmail.com, 205]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.695 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.locationsharing.config, , 210]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.696 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.locationsharing.config, tayb125.ta@gmail.com, 210]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.697 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.auth_folsom, , 2]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.700 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.auth_folsom, tayb125.ta@gmail.com, 2]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.701 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.trustagent, , 212]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.702 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.trustagent, tayb125.ta@gmail.com, 212]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.703 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.trustlet_onbody, , 203]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.704 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.trustlet_onbody, tayb125.ta@gmail.com, 203]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.705 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.languageprofile, , 201]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.706 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.languageprofile, tayb125.ta@gmail.com, 201]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.707 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.gconnect, , 1]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.710 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.gconnect, tayb125.ta@gmail.com, 1]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.712 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.car_setup, , 210]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.713 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.car_setup, tayb125.ta@gmail.com, 210]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.714 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.devicedoctor, , 208]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.715 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.devicedoctor, tayb125.ta@gmail.com, 208]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.716 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [alt.com.google.android.gms.devicedoctor, , 208]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.717 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [alt.com.google.android.gms.devicedoctor, tayb125.ta@gmail.com, 208]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.718 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.auth_api_early_update, , 3]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.719 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.auth_api_early_update, tayb125.ta@gmail.com, 3]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.720 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.locationsharing, , 212]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.721 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.locationsharing, tayb125.ta@gmail.com, 212]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.722 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.apps.maps, , 985201143]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.723 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.apps.maps, tayb125.ta@gmail.com, 985201143]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.725 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.oauthintegrations#com.google.android.apps.maps, , 17]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.726 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.oauthintegrations#com.google.android.apps.maps, tayb125.ta@gmail.com, 17]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.726 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.semanticlocation, , 105]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.728 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.semanticlocation, tayb125.ta@gmail.com, 105]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.729 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.notifications, , 209]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.730 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.notifications, tayb125.ta@gmail.com, 209]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.731 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.vision, , 1800]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.732 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.vision, tayb125.ta@gmail.com, 1800]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.733 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.vision.sdk, , 1800]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.734 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.vision.sdk, tayb125.ta@gmail.com, 1800]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.735 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.fonts, , 226]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.737 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gms.fonts, tayb125.ta@gmail.com, 226]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.738 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gm, , 60362688]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.742 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.gm, tayb125.ta@gmail.com, 60362688]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.743 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.apps.tachyon, , 2263968]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.760 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.android.apps.tachyon, tayb125.ta@gmail.com, 2263968]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.765 32306-20762/? E/XXX: Going to delete [com.google.apps.drive.android, , 181520134]
2018-11-16 15:04:55.767 4720-4804/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{4fb27ff u0 com.malik.testapplication/com.malik.testapplication.ViewDirections EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true win.mViewVisibility=0, caller=com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:748 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:732 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5523 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowAnimator.stepAnimationLocked:517 com.android.server.wm.TaskStack.stepAppWindowsAnimation:2018
```

Comment: There is always possibility to add logcat.

Comment: I am trying to add let me try once more

Comment: What is the line 117 of `ViewDirections.kt`? I assume this line `ParserTask().execute(response.body()!!.toString())`, and maybe response.body() is null?

Answer (score 0):

`getLastLocation()` method that you are using for initializing mLastLocation can return null.

So because of this you had NullPointerException at this line

```
 val origin = StringBuilder(mLastLocation!!.latitude.toString())
```